# Date time picker with mobile xpages

Tags: mobile, xpages, jquery-ui-datepicker, lotus-domino, datetimepicker

I realize a mobile application with xpages.I am having a problem with the date time picker that appears not perfectly on mobile device.
I tried to incorporate uidatepicker of jquery, but again I encounter a problem in binding data with the forms (value="#{document1.Date}" does not seem to be working).
Is there another way to have a date time picker functional for xpages mobile application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile browsers do HTML5. So set the application property to HTML5 and use the date attribute of HTML5. Then you get the native picket of the respective platform.

Comment: Thanks, i did it and the date field working correctly on ios.But i didn't find a way to bind data.
    <input type="date" name="startDate" value ="#{document1.Workflow_Date}"></input>

Comment: Use a normal xp:input field and add the type HTML property in all properties